# Adding Anchor Tag Tracking to Google Universal Analytics

Tags: google-analytics, anchor, universal, universal-analytics

I've read all 9 of the articles on SO, but none of them are working. My hope is that someone has a simple answer for this.

We have a site, www.fishales.com. It is a paralax, single page site with 6 different sections. By default, GA doesn't register any of the clicks to the anchor tags. So when you look at the GA dashboard, it shows super high bounce rate, exit rate because people get all the info from 1 page.

Here is what we have added directly before the end body tag:

```
<script>
  (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
  (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
  m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
  })(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

  ga('create', 'UA-53549640-1', {'allowAnchor': true});
  ga('send', 'pageview', { 'page': location.pathname + location.search + location.hash});

jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    var hashtag = /#\S+/
    jQuery('.GATMenu a').click(function(){
        var match = jQuery(this).attr('href').match(hashtag);
        ga('send', 'pageview', '/' + match[0]);
    })
});
</script>
```

AS for the menu links, this is the code:

```
<ul class="GATMenu">
        <li><a href="#beer">beers</a></li>
        <li><a href="#food">menu</a></li>
        <li><a href="#events">events</a></li>
        <li><a href="http://fishales.com/Images/Gallery/1.jpg" class="fresco" data-fresco-group="gallery" data-fresco-caption="Fish Ale">Gallery</a></li>
        <li><a href="#about">our story</a></li>
        <li><a href="#contact">contact</a></li>
    </ul>
```

However, GA has completely stopped working since we implemented this. Any ideas oh wise ones?

Comment: Your page currently doesn't contain the jQuery code as you've pasted above, but once I paste it in via the console, I can see the pageview hits are being sent. Are you checking in your Real-Time reports to see if you see your hits? Just a matter of best practice, the tracking code should be in the <head> tags.

Comment: Ha, sorry you caught me in the middle of dev (on live, I know! shame shame). I now see the requests going off... will monitor the next 30 mins and see...

Comment: OK, let me send in another visit right now. You can try to see where I'm from.

Comment: By the way, you've probably already noticed, but the "Gallery" isn't tracked because the code results in an error: Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: http://fishales.com/Images/Gallery/1.jpg.

Comment: Is everything working now?